# How to free up Memory Usage after a Function Call? (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-phone-8.1, out-of-memory

I have a windows phone 8.1 app that when it opens a certain XAML page, it will automatically do some processing without user interaction. The problem is that when the processes are still ongoing, the memory usage keeps on increasing (I check memory usage using alt+F2). The memory usage reaches over 300 mb since I'm working with **WriteableBitmapEx**, **FileRandomAccessStream**, **IRandomAccessStream** and **Stream** methods. However, I have made sure that each stream related methods are ***disposed*** by placing it inside an **using()** statement.

Here is my sample code structure:

```
private async void MainProcess()
{
    obj x = await HelperProcess1;
    obj y = await HelperProcess2;
    obj z = await HelperProcess3;

    //... Some method here that uses x, y, and z.
}

private async Task<obj> HelperProcess1()
{
    //... Some method here.
    return obj;
}

private async Task<obj> HelperProcess2()
{
    //... Some method here.
    return obj;
}

private async Task<obj> HelperProcess3()
{
    //... Some method here.
    return obj;
}
```

There are times that my app will crash because of the **Out of Memory Exceptions** and I still have lots of processes that I need to add in this particular XAML page. Unless the **MainProcess()** ends and returns to the UI Control, the memory usage keeps on increasing. I think my code structure is wrong or there may be a better workaround for my scenario, if that's the case, please tell me the best code structure in which I can free the memory usage each time a call on a particular function or method ends/returned.

Comment: Please come up with a *real* question title, summarizing your problem, instead of just repeating tags.